# TabIndex for dynamically create

Tags: c#, tabindex

I have a few controls that I am creating at runtime and then add to some form of container (in my case a panel). While creating the controls I also set the TabIndex of each one. Now, I start at the last control (TextBox #4) and work forward so that the first control eventually ends up at the top.
[image]

I am taking into account that I'm doing this in reverse when setting the `TabIndex`, but when I actually run the code and press the Tab key it always jumps from #4 -> #3 -> #2 -> #1 (in the order they were created, not top to bottom like I would want). When debugging I can see each controls `TabIndex` is set correctly (TextBox#1.TabIndex = 1, ..., TextBox#4.TabIndex = 4) Am I missing something or is there some workaround?

**Code:**

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
(for int i = fields.Count -1; i <= 0; i--)
{
   Label lbl = new Label();
   //do some stuff with label
   lbl.TabIndex = (i + 1);
   pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: I assume i <= 0 is typo?  :) Setting TabIndex after the add might work. Suspect adding it to the panel is overwriting it in your code

Answer (score 0):

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> By default, the first control drawn has a TabIndex value of 0, the
>   second has a TabIndex of 1, and so on.

So I can only assume your +1 is incorrect.

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
(for int i = fields.Count -1; i <= 0; i--)
{
   Label lbl = new Label();
   //do some stuff with label
   lbl.TabIndex = i;
   pnl.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```